# Where did Rendering go in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Looks like the Rendering settings aren't where they used to be (i.e. enable paint flashing, show layer borders, show FPS meter, Show scrolling perf issues).

How can I access those features again?

Answer (score 48):

The Rendering settings have been moved as of **Chrome 48**. You can now access them via three-dots menu icon, More Tools, Rendering Settings.

[image: Moved Rendering Settings]

Alternatively, you can access it via the bottom pane's new menu:

[image]

Comment: In 46, that menu item reads "Inspect devices...". Any ideas where I can find rendering settings in version 46?

Comment: @Killroy Should be the same as previous versions. Open the drawer with `esc` and click the Rendering tab.

Comment: Nope, no such tabs. Only: "Console | Emulation | Promises"

Answer (score 14):

On **Windows Chrome 70.0**. Open devtools: *CTRL + SHIFT + J*.

Then click on vertical menu button highlighted below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just in case anyone else is still looking for this... I'm using Chrome 51, but I found it in the three dots menu -> More Tools -> Rendering Settings.

[image: screenshot-clip]

Comment: I'm using v51 but don't have this menu. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly，Click the button**

[image]

**Secondly，Select rendering option**

[image]

**Thirdly，You should scroll up Console**

[image]