# Force Chrome to use font from url instead of using local version

Tags: css, fonts

For testing purposes, I would like Chrome to ignore my CSS's font source priority: The priority is "first local versions, and if not found locally, then load from url":

```
/* sans latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Source Sans Pro Regular'), local('SourceSansPro-Regular'), url('font/source/sans-latin.woff2') format('woff2'), url('font/source/sans-all.woff') format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

As my development computer has "Source Sans Pro Regular" and/or "SourceSansPro-Regular" installed, Chrome always uses these local font versions. But I want to test what happens when those local versions don't exist, thereby making Chrome use the url version.

I'm aware of *[Can I force the browser to use CSS @font-face instead of font installed on system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959365/can-i-force-the-browser-to-use-css-font-face-instead-of-font-installed-on-syste)*, but with *this* question here I'm looking for a development switch or similar.

Comment: Why you can't simple delete local file?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini
> Why you can't simple delete local file?

Because the "local" font files are operating system-installed files. I need them for other purposes such as word processing.

Comment: Could you substitute a different value for local() in your testing environment? Something that doesn't exist: e.g. local('doesnotexist')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Using Chrome 95)

To ignore `local(..)` fonts, open *Chrome DevTools* and [open the *Rendering* tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52960284/923560). There is an option *Disable local fonts*. When this option is disabled, from the next page reload onwards, `local(..)` sources will be ignored.